# How can I step out of a big task on a project?

Tags: professionalism

Months ago, I accepted an offer via Discord to build a website. Since I would enter on a job on web development, I accepted (the project is no way related to my job).

My skills are not the best (~6 months) so I was assigned with a full-stack web developer so we could work together on the project.

I took this as a personal challenge and because I could ask for help, it would be a pleasant experience.

However, in the last couple of months I get drained out when I get out of my full-time job so there is little time/patience to do this extra job.

I'm, obviously, delaying this project with my lack of work and I don't wanna to affect the team as well so I'm thinking of leaving this big project but I still want to be on the developer team but probably with smaller tasks (maintaning code, etc..).

This will have some impact on the manager of the project.

How can I say to him that I'm not capable of doing this big task (building all the frontpage) but I'm able to do smaller ones and I don't want to leave his team?

I also want to highlight that this project is voluntary.

**Update**: Sadly, this project I was talking about was shutdown(ed). I thank everyone for helping out on my question.

---

I found [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/90213/how-should-i-approach-pulling-out-of-a-project) while asking, it's certainly interesting but doesn't apply that much to my question.

Comment: Why do you want to stay on this other development team when you already have a job?

Comment: Are you concerned about the legal aspects (in which case, what contracts have you signed, if any) or the professional/ethical aspects?

Comment: @Twyxz I accepted this as a challenge and **before** I got this job I'm currently on.

Comment: @PhilipKendall not at all, I didn't sign anything, I'm just looking for the best approach to speak to him. I really like the project and I'm able to support it, not on making this task.

Comment: But you want to pass on the challenge now as you are unable to complete it due to work? So why do you want to stay with that team

Comment: @Twyxz "I really like the project and I'm able to support it, not on making this task" (which is basically building the frontpage from scratch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you manage to skip this task and after a few days you are assigned another task that you dislike or feel you are not capable of completing. Are you going to try to skip it as well?

My point is, this is professional life, you don't get to do only what you want. Also, you wrote that you took this gig as a personal challenge. Why then are you trying to jump ship as soon as said challenge appears?

Approach your manager/team lead and explain to him that you feel a little overwhelmed because you don't have much experience and, therefore, don't know how to do X, Y and Z. If he feels he is wasting time with you on this task, he will assign it to someone else.

If he still thinks you should do it, talk to your colleages whenever you don't know how to do something and can't figure out on your own.

You don't have much experience, so it is really normal to feel that you can't do stuff on your own, but the only way to improve is tackling the hard stuff and persisting.

Comment: Well, I like this answer :p you're right about that though.